# Does the 969973-3 SMD receptacle need mounting holes?

Tags: connector, surface-mount, footprint

I am designing a board that uses a [969973-3](https://ro.farnell.com/amp-te-connectivity/969973-3/receptacle-smt-2x3way/dp/9689737) wire-to-board receptacle. In its [drawing](https://www.farnell.com/cad/1747780.pdf?_ga=2.155807922.863031910.1558706202-1317626412.1555699690) there are specified six 1.2 mm (mounting?) holes.

**Does anybody know what are they used for?**

I've seen pictures and 3D models for this connector and have not observed any body plastic parts that may be present on its bottom side, that may fit in those holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like it's possible to poke a wire or mating connector all the way through the board, or insert a wire or mating connector from the back of the board, if those holes are present. This allows easy board stacking without needing the full height of the connector between the boards.

In fact, this seems to be corroborated by these sections of the linked drawing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice that note 5, "Only with the bottom entry" is specifically marked on the holes you're asking about, and that note 3 states that top and bottom entry are both options for this device.

Comment: Please confirm if I understood correctly: the connector has holes in its body that allows one to insert a wire all the way through the board and connector?

Comment: Right, if I'm reading the drawing correctly the pin holes in the connector are open on both sides. If you have an additional opening on the board then you can put a wire all the way through, or insert a wire from the back.

Comment: Interesting. I've never used this feature. Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: @CristianM I found information in the drawing that confirms this, too; check the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you again. I've seen that information, but I did not understood it.

Comment: You're welcome! If you think this answered your question, you can click the upward-pointing triangle beside it to upvote it, and the checkmark to say "this is the answer that worked for me"; this will help people find the right answer if there are others, and the checkmark will let people know the question has been answered to your satisfaction. Of course, others may also post better answers, so you may want to hold off on marking this as the best answer.

Comment: I would encourage you to change your answer some. You would not insert "wires" into this type of connector. Instead you would be using a mating dual row header connector (open pins spaced 2.54mm by 2.54mm) that can enter the subject connector from either the top or from the bottom if the 1.2mm holes are drilled through the board as shown in the suggested foot print.

Comment: Bottom entry allows for board stacking where the lower board has pin headers and the top board pushes down onto the pins.

Comment: @MichaelKaras The asker referred to it as a wire-to-board connector, as does Farnell. There may be a mating connector, but I don't think that's the only intended use.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I have edited the answer to mention this, though. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks for the rewording. But trust me you would never just insert wires into this connector. A wire-to-board connector system is a scheme to transition a cable of wires to a circuit board.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I certainly would if I was using it for a devboard for prototyping purposes. But that's fair; you certainly wouldn't be any worse off using a dedicated  wire terminal at the very least. PCB mount terminal blocks are the way to go for true direct-wire-to-board connections.